# Bootstrap Slider change value handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I'm using Bootstrap Slider, and I was wondering if there is any way to include a handler for a value change. I see that the documentation includes handlers for slideStart, slide and slideStop, but none for "change" (of value).

It's possible that they could slide the slider around and (upon release) end up on the same value, in which case I would NOT want the event to fire. Only if they slide it to a new value.

I've tried:

```
$('#sliderAdminType').slider({
    formater: function(value) {
        // my formater stuff that works
        },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("has changed");
        }       
    });
```

and

```
$('#sliderAdminType').change(function() {
    console.log("has changed");
});
```

and

```
$('#sliderAdminType').slider().change(function() {
    console.log("has changed");
});
```

and

```
$('body').on('change', '#sliderAdminType', function(e){
    console.log("has changed");
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do the following steps:

1) Use `slideStart` event to get the original value of your slider

2) Use `slideStop` event to get the new value of your slider

3) Compare this two value, if it's different then fire your code

```
var originalVal;

$('.span2').slider().on('slideStart', function(ev){
    originalVal = $('.span2').data('slider').getValue();
});

$('.span2').slider().on('slideStop', function(ev){
    var newVal = $('.span2').data('slider').getValue();
    if(originalVal != newVal) {
        alert('Value Changed!');
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kuB8/27/)**

Comment: Thank you. I knew I could do a workaround like this, I was just hoping there was a way to trigger the usual change handler and I was just missing something. :) If it turns out that is not possible, I will use this option. Thanks!

Comment: @Lys777 I believe there is no event as `change` in bootstrap slider since I've go through all their docs many times already :)

Comment: Be careful! Current implementation of 'change', 'slideStart', 'slideStop' are triggered on mouse move. I asked why there is a bit unexpected implementation and the aswer was it the way how the plugin works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was making Ajax Calls on Change and it used to make Ajax call for each point while sliding the slider. Now after this it makes only one ajax call when the slider stops.

Comment: @Felix - What should I do to perform event for clickable on slider bar?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is not valid for **range: true** slider

Here is double-slider check: https://jsfiddle.net/oayj5Lhb/

**For double slider:** "change" event returns both **newValue** and **oldValue** objects. Keep in mind that 'change', 'slideStart', 'slideStop' events ***are triggered on mouse move*** (when I asked why the answer was "this is the proper way of implementation", for me it looks a bit strange). Here an example:

```
$('#your-slider').slider().on('change', function(event) {
    var a = event.value.newValue;
    var b = event.value.oldValue;

    var changed = !($.inArray(a[0], b) !== -1 && 
                    $.inArray(a[1], b) !== -1 && 
                    $.inArray(b[0], a) !== -1 && 
                    $.inArray(b[1], a) !== -1 && 
                    a.length === b.length);

    if(changed ) {
        //your logic should be here
    }
});
```

---

**Please note:** [2, 1] and [1, 2] are considired to be equal because slider pair can be interchangeable.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. 'slideStart', 'slideStop' would trigger my code if I just clicked on the Ticker. "change" works onl after there is a change in value.

Answer (score 5):

try this if on function didn't work for you like me

`$('#yourSlider').bind("slideStop", function (e)`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when I didn't want to call slider() again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of change event just use the slide. The promoter is not working well, so in Slide you can set value again.

```
        var thresholdSlider = $('#Threshold');
        thresholdSlider.slider({
            formater: function (value) {
                return 'Current value: ' + value;
            }
        });

        thresholdSlider.slider().on('slide', function (ev) {
            thresholdSlider.slider('setValue', ev.value);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to figure this out myself and this is the solution I found with jquery, when the slider is moved:

```
$('#sliderAdminType').on('input', function() {
   console.log($('#sliderAdminType').val());
});
```

This is the resource where I found the partial answer:
[codegrepper.com](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/range+slider+onchange)