# Bootstrap range slider change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-slider

I wanted to trigger an event when the bootstrap range slider value changes and then wanted to perform some ajax.The range slider is for price.

This is my ajax:

```
 var ajaxCallBack = function (e) {

            var input = $(this).val();

            if ( input.length >= 2 ) {
                $('#spinner').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "{{ path('search') }}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {search:  $('#form_search').val(), brand: $('#form_brand').val(), price: $('#form_price').val()},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('.card-deck').html(response.classifiedList);
                        $('#spinner').hide();
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I have tried many options, but nothing helped.

Could anyone please help!

Comment: The code you pasted has nothing to do with a slider, are you having issues with the range slider change event or with the posting of the value of it with AJAX??

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 Sorry, I have implemented the bootstrap slider in the form already. I shall paste that code also. But my real problem is when the value of the slider changes, i wanted to perform something. So i wanted to to know when the value changed and how to trigger that!

Comment: added an example just now.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the events listed at https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#events

```js
$('#ex1').slider({
 formatter: function(value) {
  return 'Current value: ' + value;
 }
}).on('change', change); // Change the 'change' to any other event slide, slideStart, etc.


function change(e){
    $('.card-deck').html($(this).val() + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>

<div class="card-deck">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21869493/7231415

Looks like you have to use slideStart and slideStop events

Also take a look at angularJS, there is a directive called
ng-change which can be used to handle events,

or you could bind a ng-model variable to it and watch for changes